unknown variable 'mysql-native-password=ON'
I am using Docker and MySQL for some projects. I am having some issues because of the removal of mysql_native_password plugin on MySQL 8.4 by default. I have followed the instructions to enable it and it worked correctly last week.
Did this:

Added command: --mysql-native-password=ON on the image

This week I am having this error unknown variable 'mysql-native-password=ON on the same infrastructure as last week.
Can someone help me with this one because it is very confusing?

Did you upgrade your MySQL version recently?
I am always pulling the latest image of MySQL using docker, and noticed the same issue as you. In hindsight, that might not have been wise. For me, the issue occured when MySQL updated from 8.x.x to 9.x.x:
And indeed, after looking at the patch notes, I see:

The mysql_native_password authentication plugin, deprecated in MySQL
8.0, has been removed, and the server now rejects mysql_native authentication requests from older client programs which do not have
CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH capability. For backward compatibility,
mysql_native_password remains available on the client; the client-side
built-in authentication plugin has been converted into a dynamically
loadable plugin. Note
These changes also entail the removal of the following server options
and variables:
The --mysql-native-password server option


https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/9.0/en/news-9-0-0.html
If you've upgraded to 9.x.x, it's difficult to downgrade. You'll may have to find another way to authenticate...
